# A form of Baire's Category Theorem

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $X$ is a complete metric space and $(U_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable collection of open dense subsets of $X$ then prove that the set $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$ is also dense in $X$.
$$$$Let us chose any arbitrary point $x$ member of $X$ then as $U_1$ is dense in $X$, so $x$ is an accumulation point of $U_1$. Now chose any arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$ say $$B_{\epsilon}(x)=(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$$. Then there exists a $y_1$ in this neighborhood and also $y_1$ belongs to $U_1$ and as $U_1$ is an open set so there exists a $\delta_1$ such that the interval $$[y_1-\delta_1, y_1+\delta_1]$$ lies in both $U_1$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ and whose width is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Now as $U_2$ is dense in $X$, so there exists a $y_2$ member of $U_2$ in the interval $$(y_1-\delta_1, y_1+\delta_1)$$. Now again as $U_2$ is an open set, so there exists a $\delta_2$ such that the interval $$[y_2-\delta_2, y_2+\delta_2]$$ lies in both $U_2$ and $$[y_1-\delta_1, y_1+\delta_1]$$ ans whose width is less than $(\frac{1}{2})^2$. Continuing in the similar way we will get a $y_n$ member of $U_n$ and a $\delta_n$ such that the interval $$[y_n-\delta_n, y_n+\delta_n]$$ lies in both $U_n$ and $$[y_{n-1}-\delta_{n-1}, y_{n-1}+\delta_{n-1}]$$ and whose width is less than $(\frac{1}{2})^n$. So we get a Nested sequence of closed intervals whose width is converging to $0$ and hence there is a $y$ which lies in all such intervals. Now it is easy to see that the $n^{th}$ closed inteval lies in all the $m^{th}$ interval with $m \leq n$ and as $m^{th}$ interval lies in the set $U_m$ so the $n^{th}$ interval lies in all the sets $U_m$ with $m \leq n$ and hence $y$ lies in the set $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$. And hence for any $x$ member of $X$ and in any arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$ we can find a $y$ which belongs to the set $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$ and hence every point $x$ is an accumulation point of the set $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$ and hence the set $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$$ is dense in $X$
$$$$I want to know that in the proof there is no use of complete metric space, so where is the fault??

Comment: Your use of intervals makes no sense for general metric spaces, replace them with open and closed balls resepctively. Apart from that, what gives you "and hence there is a $y$ which lies in all such intervals"? (For $\mathbb{R}$, the nested interval intersection property is one of the equivalent ways to state completeness. For general metric spaces, something analogous holds.)

Comment: A metric space is complete if and only if every numerable family of nested and closed balls such that the sequence of radious tends to zero has a non empty intersection (theorem of nested and closed balls)
In your proof indirectly you are using that property of complete spaces although you are dealing with closed intervals. As Daniel Fischer mentioned, just change closed intervals with closed balls and everything holds.

Answer (score 1):

One condition equivalent to completeness is:

> A nested sequence of closed sets with diameter tending to zero has nonempty intersection.

You have used this.

Comment: But this property can hold in any general metric space

Comment: This property fails in the rationals (with the usual metric).  Can you come up with a sequence of closed intervals that decrease to $\sqrt{2}$, so that in the rationals the intersection is empty?